# Как в R получить таблицу со смешанным форматом чисел?

Tags: r, format, data.frame

Вывожу описательные статистики из `pastecs::stat.desc()`.
 Последним пунктом в таблице идет значимость теста на нормальность, соответственно, она представляет из себя число, наподобие этого: 0.00000000000000000000345.
R выдает сначала в научном формате всё. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда просишь этого не делать и даже ставишь ограничение `digits = 3` у всех чисел в таблице все равно миллион нулей, я так подозреваю что как раз из-за этой значимости. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос: как в R указать, какие числа мне нужны в обычном виде, а какие в научном?

Comment: Пример - в студию!

Comment: да пожалуйста =)

Comment: sapply(rnorm(10), round, 3) Вместо rnorm(10) - любые значения, требующие округления.

Comment: сохрани результат как отдельный df и потом преобразовывай колонки как хочешь. Вот тут вроде подробно описано как менять формат http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706677/how-to-display-numeric-columns-in-an-r-dataframe-without-scientific-notation-e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что в объектах класса `data.frame` данные одного типа (разрядности) должны соответствовать колонкам, а не строкам. Функция `stat.desc()` объединяет разные статистические показатели в один столбец, который соответствует анализируемой переменной. Это приводит к тому, что в одном столбце оказываются числа совершенно разной разрядности, форматирование должно охватить все данные в столбце.

Наиболее корректным выходом в данном случае будет транспонировать таблицу:

```
library(pastecs)
data(marbio)
options(digits = 3, scipen = 9999, width = 80)
t(stat.desc(marbio[,13:16], norm = TRUE))
#>             nbr.val nbr.null nbr.na min  max range    sum median    mean
#> Nauplii          68        0      0   3  636   633   9018    104  132.62
#> Oithona          68        0      0  39 7792  7753 105159   1228 1546.46
#> Acanthaires      68        8      0   0   52    52    987     12   14.51
#> Cladocerans      68       45      0   0  200   200    394      0    5.79
#>             SE.mean CI.mean.0.95     var std.dev coef.var skewness skew.2SE
#> Nauplii       12.54        25.03   10696     103    0.780     2.04     3.50
#> Oithona      155.44       310.26 1642972    1282    0.829     2.58     4.43
#> Acanthaires    1.46         2.91     145      12    0.829     0.91     1.56
#> Cladocerans    3.04         6.06     627      25    4.321     6.95    11.94
#>             kurtosis kurt.2SE normtest.W            normtest.p
#> Nauplii        6.434    5.604      0.824 0.0000001507163975527
#> Oithona        8.866    7.723      0.754 0.0000000024574084329
#> Acanthaires    0.539    0.469      0.918 0.0002736261633929842
#> Cladocerans   50.391   43.894      0.225 0.0000000000000000375
```

Если же необходимо во что бы то ни стало сохранить ориентацию таблицы, то можно использовать следующий вариант форматирования, который, впрочем, также не лишён недостатков:

```
format(round(x, 3), trim = TRUE, nsmall = 3)
#>                Nauplii     Oithona Acanthaires Cladocerans
#> nbr.val         68.000      68.000      68.000      68.000
#> nbr.null         0.000       0.000       8.000      45.000
#> nbr.na           0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000
#> min              3.000      39.000       0.000       0.000
#> max            636.000    7792.000      52.000     200.000
#> range          633.000    7753.000      52.000     200.000
#> sum           9018.000  105159.000     987.000     394.000
#> median         104.000    1228.000      12.000       0.000
#> mean           132.618    1546.456      14.515       5.794
#> SE.mean         12.542     155.439       1.459       3.036
#> CI.mean.0.95    25.034     310.258       2.912       6.060
#> var          10696.478 1642971.655     144.731     626.763
#> std.dev        103.424    1281.785      12.030      25.035
#> coef.var         0.780       0.829       0.829       4.321
#> skewness         2.038       2.579       0.910       6.945
#> skew.2SE         3.504       4.435       1.565      11.943
#> kurtosis         6.434       8.866       0.539      50.391
#> kurt.2SE         5.604       7.723       0.469      43.894
#> normtest.W       0.824       0.754       0.918       0.225
#> normtest.p       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000
```

Answer (score 4):

С учетом вышесказанного, лучшее решение - использовать `describe()` из пакета `psych`. На основе этой функции себе для удобства сделал вот такой вариант: http://biostat-r.blogspot.com/2015/08/blog-post.html

Comment: Хотел, чтобы и на нормальность мне проверяли сразу..А идея у Вас классная

Comment: `psych::describe()` крайне не эффективная по скорости работы функция. Для локализации всё же предпочтительнее использовать `gettext()`.